# Rendering a component programmatically (not via template)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working on an Ember app that's integrated with a separate SDK that has its own custom UI components. For example,

```
<integration-name-customer-view customer-name="Bob">
```

These components have render lifecycle hooks, like `onRender`, `onCreate`, etc.

I would like to hook into the `onRender` callback and insert an Ember component I have created (a tooltip with some special functionality).

Here's what I've attempted:

**Integration-Customer-Name Definition**

```
import MyTooltip from 'ember-app/components/my-tooltip';    

...

onRender() {
    let parent = this;

    MyTooltip
        .extend({
            layout: myTemplate,
            didRender() {
                parent.appendChild(this.element);
            }
        })
        .create({ position: 'above' })
        .appendTo(document.body);
}
```

Now, this actually works, but I have two questions:

1. Is this the right thing to do? Is there a simpler way/is this going to crash and burn?
2. My template has a `{{yield}}` block in it. Is there a way to programmatically determine what is going to be rendered into that block?

Comment: Check out [ember-islands](https://github.com/mitchlloyd/ember-islands/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: I've tried ember-islands. It tells me "You cannot append to an existing Ember.View."